# escaping backslash in .vimrc to have a :map working with grep and \s

Tags: bash, vim, grep, escaping

On my `.vimrc` I use this:

```
:map ,p :!clear; grep -E "def \|class " %
```

to map `,p` to the grep that provide Python def and class hierarchy, it work very well.

I try with no success to do the same to get some vuejs structure.

I get what I need on Bash with this is `grep`:

```
$ grep -E '^\s+\S+: {|\() {$|<script>|import' /tmp/somevuejs.vue
```

But when I try to put it on `.vimrc`:

```
:map ,j :!clear; grep -E '^\s+\S+: {|\() {$|<script>|import' %
```

I get this error:

```
$ vim file.txt
Error detected while processing /home/me/.vimrc:
line   20:
E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
```

I've try multiples escapes combinatoric with no success, neither of this worked:

```
:map ,j :!clear; grep -E '^//\s+//\S+: {|\() {$|<script>|import' %
:map ,j :!clear; grep -E "^//\s+//\S+: {|\() {$|<script>|import" %
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:help map-bar` says that you can't use a `|` in a mapping unless you escape it somehow.

Your existing mapping "works" because its `|` is properly escaped:

```
:map ,p :!clear; grep -E "def \|class " %
                              ^^
```

Your new mapping doesn't work because its many `|`s are not escaped:

```
:map ,j :!clear; grep -E '^\s+\S+: {|\() {$|<script>|import' %
                                    ^      ^        ^
```

The exact error reported by Vim is caused by this construct:

```
{|\(
```

The `|` is considered by Vim as a separator between two Vim commands, so you get one Vim command:

```
:!clear; grep -E '^\s+\S+: {
```

(that executes a borked external command anyway), followed by a second one:

```
:\() {$|<script>|import' %
```

which doesn't really make sense. It's the `\` that causes the error. If you escape that first `|` you will get a different error caused by the second `|`, and then another one caused by the third `|`.

Escape those `|`s to make your mapping "work":

```
:map ,j :!clear; grep -E '^\s+\S+: {\|\() {$\|<script>\|import' %
                                    ^^      ^^        ^^
```

I put "work" in quotes because those mappings are super clunky.

1. They need a `<CR>` at the end so that you don't have to press Enter to execute the command:

   ```
   :map ,p :!clear; grep -E "def \|class " %<CR>
   :map ,j :!clear; grep -E '^\s+\S+: {\|\() {$\|<script>\|import' %<CR>
   ```
2. They should be restricted to normal mode, unless you really want them to be defined for visual, select, and operator-pending modes, too:

   ```
   :nmap ,p :!clear; grep -E "def \|class " %<CR>
   :nmap ,j :!clear; grep -E '^\s+\S+: {\|\() {$\|<script>\|import' %<CR>
   ```
3. Since you don't seem to be purposely using another mapping in your mappings, it is best to make them non-recursive:

   ```
   :nnoremap ,p :!clear; grep -E "def \|class " %<CR>
   :nnoremap ,j :!clear; grep -E '^\s+\S+: {\|\() {$\|<script>\|import' %<CR>
   ```
4. And, since you are in a script, you can safely remove the colon:

   ```
   nnoremap ,p :!clear; grep -E "def \|class " %<CR>
   nnoremap ,j :!clear; grep -E '^\s+\S+: {\|\() {$\|<script>\|import' %<CR>
   ```

That's a lot cleaner!

Now, I guess we will keep the next mystery, namely why you use an external tool for that instead of `:help :global`, for the comments… or for another question.

Comment: Thank you very clear; what confused me in the error message was "E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &" refer to "\" not to "|"

Comment: Let me expand on the exact error.